# JBoss AS 7.1.1 jboss-deployment-structure.xml

Tags: xml, jboss, ejb, ejb-3.0, jboss7.x

I'm using JBoss AS 7.1.1 and I'm having trouble getting my EJB 3.0 server project to run. I get the error

`JBAS014777: Services which failed to start: service jboss.deployment.unit."GrahamsProj.ear".STRUCTURE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."GrahamsProj.ear".STRUCTURE: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment "GrahamsProj.ear"`

I looked it up and the error seems to be something pertaining to my `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`. Here is what mine looks like:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure> 
    <deployment> 
        <dependencies> 
            <module name="org.slf4j" /> 
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

I don't know if I have any dependencies as I got the above from an example online. All I know is that the error means it doesn't like my `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` file. What can I do to get the file structured right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd delete it.

I am not an AS7 expert (is anyone, yet?), but i believe you only need it if you have particularly subtle deployment requirements. For straightforward module dependencies, you can put a [Dependencies entry in your manifest](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Class+Loading+in+AS7) instead.

However, since SLF4J is one of the [standard implicit dependencies](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Implicit+module+dependencies+for+deployments#Implicitmoduledependenciesfordeployments-Whicharetheimplicitmoduledependencies?), you don't even need to do that. You can just go ahead and use it, like you would a JDK or Java EE API.